# How to test React web app on mobie device

Tags: reactjs, security, networking, localhost, firewall

I created a web application using React and TypeScript. It's working good on PC's localhost, but I need to test it with an android device too, to make sure all my components are responsive to screen size. I tried to have both my PC and android on the same WiFi, ran the app on the localhost, and then entered: 
 
 http://{IPv4_adress}:{port_number} 
 
 However, it just keeps on loading and nothing shows up, and eventually, the chrome says 
 
"This side can't be reached" 
 {ip adress} took too long to respond 
 ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT 
 I'm using Windows10 and have McAfee installed, which may or may not be doing something to block the connetion from the mobile device. If anyone knows how to test the React app on mobile device, please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your network must be Private on windows10. and also make sure you are using ipv4 address.

Comment: Sorry, I am actually already using IPv4 address. And, also, how exactly do you mean by making the network private?

Comment: click on the wifi icon, then click on the network name, you'll see properties option, click on it, then on the network profile section, set it to Private